# Restrict users to view custom form(s) without complete other formalities

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, users

I wrote 3 custom forms using [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x) for resetting password. All forms have these functionalities.

**Form # 1.** On submit, sends OTP (code) after entering mobile number and redirect to form # 2

**From # 2.** On submit, validate OTP and redirect to form # 3

**From # 3.** The last form where user can enter password and confirm password and submit.

How to restrict user from accessing **form#2** without submit **form#1**?

```
                        AND
```

How to restrict user from accessing **form#3** without submit **form#2**?

Answer (score 0):

Check the referring page using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` if it doesn't match the previous page either throw an error or redirect him to the first page.

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail and with an example. I've tried while it will not redirect to the form # 3 however redirect to form # 2 successfully.